# How to colourize text cells automatically in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, colors

I have a table in Excel.  There are a few attribute columns for each "thing", the "thing" being the first column.  I want to quickly just add colours to everything of the same type to help visually differentiate them.  For numbers, I'll add a Conditional Formatting rule with a colour scale, and that's sufficient.

In this case though, the attribute field is text.  Sample values include: "Active", "Inactive", "Needs Review".

I don't care what value gets which colour.  I'm just looking for a simple option to automatically apply some colours without having to add a new Conditional Formatting rule for each possible text value.

The following table should have 3 colours for the Status column.

```
Client, Status
Bob's Burgers, Active
Lucy's Salad Bar, Inactive
George's Existential Crisis, Active
Other George's Pub, Needs Review
```

EDIT:
I reference Conditional Formatting twice in my question.  This question is specifically to do it *automatically* for a *spread* of *text* values, without one rule per text value - no updates for new possible values, no picking individual colours, etc.

This is an optimization for the Conditional Formatting rules already described, and not a question about how to use the feature itself.

Comment: This is called "Conditional formatting" and is a default feature in Excel. There should be a button for this in the Home tab, in the Styles section.

Comment: I talk about Conditional Formatting _in my question_.  I'm specifically looking for a way to apply a range of colours to a range of text values without setting up a specific rule for each possible text value.

Answer (score 0):

If VBA and lots of coding and work aren't going to work for you, then the quickest/easiest thing will be to create rules for each data type you're working with.

In order to automate ranking of data, a lot of work has to go into building the framework you'll be putting the data into.

Basically, you'll have to tell the application what sort of data it'll be dealing with, how that data is to be measured/ranked/compared, what can be done with the data. Lot's of information ABOUT the data.

Only after you've fully and exhaustively conveyed to the program everything ABOUT the data and how it is to be handled can you being actually entering data.

As you can see, this quickly becomes very, very big.

It's not unuseful. On the contrary, huge amounts of money are spent by people and companies who want their data sorted and ranked and measured and teased to work better for them, to be more meaningful for them. ERP, business analytics, these are huge software markets.

But, unless your data is worth a lot of money, is really, really big, you're not going to benefit from such a tool as this, and you're really better off just using the Conditional Formatting rules in Excel.

And yea, color scales can only work with data that is already understood in a generic context, like numeric values. Text data may still be useful, but once again, you have to explain WHAT that data MEANS before Excel can begin automatically ranking it.

Comment: For my needs, Excel could just take the ascii values, or an all-numeric hash, of the text and colour scale those.  Thank you for following up with this though, and assuring me that Excel doesn't have a convenient way to do this.

Comment: Man, you've got my "what if" juices stirring. So, if you recorded a macro of building the Conditional Formatting based on numeric values, and then wrote a VBA function that "converts" the ASCII values of the entered text to create those numbers (divide it by something to get a useful range of unique values, perhaps) and then passes that to the Conditional Formatting bit you just might get a shortcut. Granted, I haven't an idea what any of that would look like in code, but it would be easy to extend to a broad dataset without needing a lot of data defining pre-work.

Answer (score 0):

You can just make a sample Conditional Format, and use [Format Painter](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Copy-formatting-using-the-Format-Painter-b9fe82ea-c0a0-41de-837b-d2f15dd41ea9) to copy the format to the cell or range you want. It is only three clicks away from doing what you want.

1. Select the source cell of conditional format.
2. Click (or Shift+click, if you want to apply on non-contiguous range) Format Painter.

[image: Format Painter]

3. Click (and drag, if range) on cells you want to apply the formatting.

---

**Note** : As a side effect, any other formatting (borders, fonts, etc.) will also be applied, unfortunately.